# Cut list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List where I want to cut all the false values before the first true value and all the false values after the last true value.

I know I can do this with a loop from each direction. I am just curious if there is an easier way to do this using LINQ.

Comment: `SkipWhile()`, `TakeWhile()`, read [ask], try searching. A [mcve] demonstrating your problem would really help.

Comment: `list.GetRange(list.IndexOf(true), list.LastIndexOf(true) - list.IndexOf(true))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So given this input:

```
var input = new List<bool>
{
    false,
    false,
    true, // first true
    true,
    false,
    true, // last true
    false
};
```

You want `true, true, false, true`, right?

The trivial way would be to use `(Last)IndexOf`:

```
var firstTrue = input.IndexOf(true);
var lastTrue = input.LastIndexOf(true);

var indexed = input.Skip(firstTrue).Take(lastTrue - firstTrue + 1).ToList();
```

This will worst-case iterate the list twice, once for `IndexOf` call, and needs error checking (what if no `true` are in the input?).

If you insist on LINQ, it becomes harder, as functional prorgamming works on single items of a set as a time, not considering the set as a whole. So while evaluating for each list item whether they're to be included, you need to keep scanning forward in the list (as to not let the first `false` stop the search):

```
var output = input.SkipWhile(t => t == false)
                  .TakeWhile((b, i) => b == true || input.Skip(i + 2).Contains(true));
```

Answer (score 1):

Say your input is as follows:

```
var values= new List<bool>()
        { false, false,
          true, false, false ,true, false, true, //this is the part you want
          false, false, false};
```

The easiest way would of course be to simply get the indexes of the first and last occurrence of a `true` value, and get the contents between these two indexes.

```
if (values.Contains(true)) //check if there is actually at least one true.
{
    var firstIndex = values.IndexOf(true);
    var lastIndex = values.LastIndexOf(true);
    var count = lastIndex - firstIndex + 1; //include last index
    var result = values.GetRange(firstIndex, count);
}
```

If you really want to use LINQ, but would rather not worry about lookaheads, you can use `SkipWhile()` to skip everything up to the first `true`, then reverse the list, and `SkipWhile()` again up to the first `true`.

```
if (values.Contains(true)) //check if there is actually at least one true.
{
    var result = values.SkipWhile(x => !x).Reverse().SkipWhile(x => !x);
};
```